# Allowing update but preventing a column from being allowed in the update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to allow an update but want to exclude the update of a specific column and create it's own update method.

**Question:** Is there a way for me to define my order params but exclude a specific column? Or even separate the columns into methods?

```
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:name, :email, :image, :video, :description)
end
```

My issue is that, I have a stripe charge in my update method so when i simply update an orders "order_status", the customer gets charged.

I have a column "order_status" which can be changed by enum 1,2,3 and i want to avoid that within it the update so no charge is made.

I created:

```
def order_status
  params.permit(:order_status)
end
```

But since the original order_params has :orders, the order status is still being included.

I have the enum as, "created", "charged", and "cancelled". A seller can cancel an order with:

```
<%= form_for @order, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :order_status, value: "cancelled" %>
    <%= f.button type:'submit', class: "btn btn-danger", onclick: "refreshPage()" %>
<% end %>
```

What should i do to have this "order_status" update be on its own and out of the original update method so customers don't get charged?

**Update:**

I did find a way to simply create it's own method for charging and taking the charge out of the update method with all the params..

```
def charge_update
    respond_to do |format|
      @amount = (@order.order_price).to_i * 100
      @amount_seller = (@order.order_price).to_i * 75
      if @order.update(params[:tracking_number])
        if user_signed_in?
                      charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
                        :amount      => (@order.order_price).to_i * 100,
                        :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
                        :currency    => 'usd',
                        :customer => @order.stripe_customer_token,
                        :destination => {
                          :amount => @amount_seller ,
                          :account => (@order.seller.stripe_token),
                        }
                      })
          @order.order_status = "charged"
          format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully uploaded.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

The customer only gets charged once the order is sent.

But, how can i specify the params status itself?

For instance, I want to create a method for the order_status, but only for when the order_status = "cancelled"... and then create 2 more methods for the other 2 possibly status'
?

So when I/seller cancels an order, I can create a custom message, send emails, etc. and do the same for "charged", and "created"....

Comment: `But since the original order_params has :orders, the order status is still being included.` can you explain this a little more?

Comment: I actually figured out a way but I would still like to hear what you or others have to say in case there are other or better ways.  But by having :orders, I imagine that includes all the columns because even when i removed "order_status" it would still update.  But what I did was create a new method only for order_status like above, put the charge in there, and removed the charge from the original update method...this way it only charges when the order completes instead of random updates

Comment: You can always do something like `@order.update_column :order_status, new_value` and it will just set the value on the object, update the value on the database and nothing more (no validations, no callbacks, no nothing).

Comment: so that would be like: def xyz - if @order.update(params[:video]) - @order.update_column :order_status, "charged" - end ?? (assume "-" is a break/return) ??  This basically says, if a video is uploaded (which means an order is complete) then change status to charged?

Comment: sorry i don't think i clarified what i wanted.  I want to know how to pin point a value from a column within a method in a controller.   so if i change a column value from a view, lets say with a button, then the controller will react.  Because order_status has 3 different values and i want different reactions for each value

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for me to define my order params but exclude a specific
>   column?

Easy. The `#except` method can be used to remove a key or keys from the (whitelisted) params hash.

```
order_params.except(:order_status)
```

> Or even separate the columns into methods?

One thing to remember is that [`ActionController::Parameters`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) is actually a pretty basic hash like object and you can compose your whitelist functions however you want.

`#permit` works somewhat like [`Hash#slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-slice) on steroids - it returns a new `ActionController::Parameters` instance with the `permitted` attribute set to true. It also takes a hash argument for [nested parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#nested-parameters).

You can use also use arrays to compose whitelists from different methods. This can be pretty nifty since all the methods in ActionController::Parameters are reductive. The trick is using [the splat(*) operator](https://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/) to convert the array to a list of arguments:

```
def base_parameters
  [:a, :b, :c, :d]
end

def others
  [:e, :f]
end

def create_parameters
  params.require(:order)
        .permit(*base_parameters.concat(others))
end
```

Comment: Yeah i think you're on to it.  the best way to to simply create methods for each one that needs to be separate and define the full/original update method to specific params (or just except the ones i dont want in it..)... so if i do except, if will be like this?: if @order.update(order_params).except([:order_status]) ?

Comment: `@order.update( order_params.except(:order_status) )`. It takes a list of args - not an array.

Comment: As to the what your doing I would consider setting it up as `POST /orders/:order_id/payments` => payments#create. Try to think of a checkout process in terms of CRUD'ing restful resources.

Comment: That is essentially how i have it set up, or maybe not... i have it has orders>>stripe_account ..or are you saying to have charging in its own controller... beacuse if so, i couldn't figure out how to get it to work within the same order page... because with an order i need a form to be filled out and i want the charge to happen along with the order form and not needing to have them go to a whole new page.. idk im sure it can be done but i'm still green in coding